# Why is the SQL server DB engine not connecting with SQLAlchemy engine?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to the SQL server database on python platform using SqlAlchemy. I am using windows authentication to connect to my the SQL server. On connecting the server the SqlAlchemy engine is throwing an error:

**Below is the code I have implemented:**

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import pyodbc


              Driver         Server Name    Instance        Database
DATABASE_URL='mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-N32LSOV\PRANAV/AdventureworksDW2016CTP3?trusted_connection=yes'
Engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

cn = Engine.connect()
```

When the above code is run, this error is produced:

> Error:sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

I tried using pymssql driver inplace of pyodbc driver but still the error persists. On contrary when i try to connect to the using the below syntax it connects. I guess i am missing some attribute in the mssql url.

```
pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-N32LSOV\PRANAV;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you have not escaped the backslash in ``DATABASE_URL``. So either use a ``r""``-string or escape the backslash (``\\``). In your ``pyodbc.connect()``-call, you use ``r""``-syntax.

Comment: @codeape Hi man i tried "mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-N32LSOV\PRANAV:1433//AdventureworksDW2016CTP3?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0".                                                  
Also  tried "mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-N32LSOV\\PRANAV:1433/AdventureworksDW2016CTP3?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+10.0".  didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, I would try using the `creator` argument to `create_engine` ([documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine)):

```
def creator():
    return pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-N32LSOV\PRANAV;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

Engine = create_engine('mssql://', creator=creator)
```

Using `creator=` bypasses all connection parameters specified in the URL, so you should only pass information to specify the DB dialect in the URL.

Looking at the [`mssql+pyodbc` dialect/driver documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-pyodbc), there is also the `?odbc_connect` option:

```
import urllib.parse
CONNECTION_STRING = r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-N32LSOV\PRANAV;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
Engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING))
```

Comment: Yeah this is smooth , I guess I will be using the above function and not get messed with the other syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both that you want to use ODBC and what ODBC driver to use.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://localhost/Sandbox?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
```

If you add the `driver=` part to your database url, it should work.